# Importing Excel File into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012

I'm having the hardest time importing an Excel file with approx 300 records into SQL server without getting errors. I am getting an error that text will be truncated, but I checked and the max character count in that field is 520 characters. That should be fine importing into a Varchar(MAX) field. Any recommendations on best procedures for importing Excel files (just one tab) into SQL Server 2012? I have tried everything I can think of including editing mappings, etc, and still cannot get it to properly import.

Comment: Your varchar column might be specified to only contain a lesser number of characters, check the structure of your table.

Comment: You may be importing unicode data, this would require an nvarchar(max) field.

Comment: I got a minus 1 for asking a question? Really? I did go into the edit mappings and changed all the varchars to varchar(max) just to be safe before I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truncation error is in the import 'source' settings. In the mappings screen choose 'Edit Mappings', then you can adjust the field size. There's also an 'Edit SQL' on the mapping screen where you can wrap your fields and cast them to the correct size

```
select cast(col1 as varchar(50))...
```

Consider exporting the data to csv and then do the import. I always have formatting issues with Excel, especially with dates.

Comment: Thanks @dito003! I took your advice and importing as CSV instead which gave me more flexibility and options. I changed the appropriate datafields under advanced for the CSV options. I got all my data in! Thanks!